# Identifying rust on steel bars in images

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I am exploring methods of identifying rust on steelwork in images similar to the one linked here: [Rusty steel bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Pte.jpg).

Currently I'm just applying simple image processing techniques to the whole image to pick up particular shades of red/brown/orange to identify the rust. The problem I'm having is that this also identifies regions of the background (anything that isn't steel) as rust as well, which is to be expected. So I need to eliminate this noise to make my results more reliable.

One idea I've looked into is segmenting out the steelwork in the image and applying the simple image processing techniques to only the steel, which would eliminate any noise from the background. However, I'm a newbie to computer vision and I have no idea where to start with something like this.

So, my question is, are there any particular image segmentation techniques you would recommend for such a task? And are there any resources out there I could use for learning how to go about applying such techniques?

An idea I've had is to train an image segmentation model in keras, which I have not done before and would therefore require a significant amount of time in learning how to do so and also preparing the data.

Also, to return to the original problem, are there any other methods I could explore for isolating the rust on the steelwork without picking up noise from the background?

Thanks!

Comment: go through this - https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/